# Display image from xml in a link

Tags: php, xml

when I read an image form a xml file how can I displayit in a link? for example using this code:

img.php

```
 $what = 'ResourceLink';

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('http://www.file.xml/getRecordsX.do?user=user01&password=password01&identifier=978841580114-6&metadataformat=ONIX&version=3.0');
while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
        $exp = $reader->expand();
        if ($exp->nodeName == $what)
            echo '<img src="' . $exp->nodeValue .' " height="15%" width="15%" />';
    }
}
```

link.php

```
<img class="foto" src="img.php?id=9788477828921" width="70" title="TIERRA VISTA DESDE EL CIELO, LA" alt="TIERRA VISTA DESDE EL CIELO, LA" border="0">';
```

I would like to pass the id, send it and display the image in the link without ajax.

was a stupid mistake. I was sending headers before using the code. This runs fine. Thanks and apollogies

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$what = 'ResourceLink';
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('http://file.xml/getRecordsX.do?user=user01&password=pass01&identifier='.$id.'&metadataformat=ONIX&version=3.0');
while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
        $exp = $reader->expand();
        if ($exp->nodeName == $what)
           $img = $exp->nodeValue;
    }}
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
readfile($img);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean! Are you able to display the image at all and just want to convert it to a link?

Comment: How does link.php relate to img.php?

Comment: I think OP is asking how to serve the image from a PHP script.  ie. `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`.  The misleading part is the `<img...` stuff in img.php.  Assume that is where OP is confused and wants that to actually serve the image.  Question could use a little elaboration I think.